# Fluent NHibernate, Generic UserTypeConvention<>

Tags: c#, generics, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have a custom type in my system, `Type<T>`.

To map it with Fluent NHibernate, I have a custom IUserType.

```
public class GenericType<T> : IUserType
```

This maps the type in the expected way when used in the fluent mapping as such:

```
Map(x => x.Property).CustomType<GenericType<BusinessClass>>()
```

I'd like to have this as a convention, such that all properties of type `Type<T>`should be  `CustomType<GenericType<T>>`.

Normally I'd use a convention of `UserTypeConvention<TUserType>`. But the syntax for this class, `GenericTypeConvention<T> : UserTypeConvention<GenericType<T>>` doesn't seem to work. I'm guessing that Fluent NHibernate doesn't check generic conventions?

Is there a way to solve this using a convention, or is the only solution to append a custom type to all mappings of properties of type `Type<T>`?